# MVC linq query handle situation where sequence contains no elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a simple login form on my mvc application and it works correctly except for when you try to login with a user that isn't in the database.

It will throw an error `Sequence contains no elements` which makes sense since theres no matching users in the database although I try to handle it in the code it is not doing it.

```
    // POST: Login User
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
    {

        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var usr = db.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.UserPassword == UserPassword);
            if (usr != null)
            {
                Session["UserID"] = usr.UserId.ToString();
                Session["Username"] = usr.UserName.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password Incorrect");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `SingleOrDefault`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning linq, do I just throw that at the end of the query?

Comment: No, instead of `Single`, use `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Oh wow I must have missed that in the tutorial I read, thanks for the answer. If you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept since I'm sure I'll need to come back to this when I forget :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Single` will throw an exception if no match is found, or too many are found. Using `SingleOrDefault` like so returns null in the case where no match is found:

```
var usr = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(...)
```

This sets you up for the null check you're doing right afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

So...As some people said in the comments above, you could just simply use the following query and then do your null check:

```
var usr = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.UserPassword == UserPassword);
```

That being said, I would recommend looking into using the built in ASP Identity framework for authentication and authorization - unless you need a custom implementation for your application, you can avoid a lot of testing (and potential bugs) as well as get a ton of cool out-of-the-box features. I would recommend checking out [the resources here](http://www.asp.net/identity) for more information.